# Rename multiple file of different extension with the same name in the incremental order

Tags: python, path, file-rename, file-extension, os.path

I have multiple folders in which I have files named as follows:

```
   1500001.jpg
   1500001.xml
   1600002.jpg
   1600002.xml
   9876543.jpg
   9876543.xml
```

As you can see I have one jpg file and its corresponding xml file with the same file name. I want to rename all these files as follows:

```
   ID_0001.jpg (1500001.jpg converted to ID_0001.jpg)
   ID_0001.xml (1500001.xml converted to ID_0001.xml)
   ID_0002.jpg (1600002.jpg converted to ID_0002.jpg)
   ID_0002.xml (1600002.xml converted to ID_0002.xml
   ID_0003.jpg (9876543.jpg converted to ID_0003.jpg)
   ID_0003.xml (9876543.xml converted to ID_0003.xml)
```

I am new to Python and have written some code for renaming files with different extension but not able to scale this to keeping the same filename for its corresponding file in the incremental order like ID_0001.jpg, ID_0001.xml, etc.

```
import os
_src = "path/to/directory"
_ext_jpg = ".jpg"
_ext_xml = ".xml"

for i,filename in enumerate(os.listdir(_src)):
    if filename.endswith(_ext_jpg):
        os.rename(filename, _src+'ID_' + str(i)+_ext_jpg)

    else:
        os.rename(filename, _src+'ID_' + str(i)+_ext_xml)
```

With this code, the increment happens for the all the files like ID_0001.jpg, ID_002.xml, ID_003.jpg, ID_004.xml and actually it should be like ID_0001.jpg, ID_0001.xml , ID_0002.jpg, ID_0002.xml, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a filename, rename both the `xml` and `jpg` files:

```
import os
_src = "path/to/directory"
_ext_jpg = ".jpg"
_ext_xml = ".xml"

for i,filename in enumerate(os.listdir(_src)):
    if filename.endswith(_ext_jpg):
        os.rename(filename, _src+'ID_' + str(i)+_ext_jpg)
        os.rename(filename[:-4]+_ext_xml, _src+'ID_' + str(i)+_ext_xml)
```

Comment: My path directory is  _src = r'C:\Users\Documents\data\docs\image_with_xml' 
After running the code, the files are getting saved in docs folder named as 'image_with_xmlID_0.jpg' , 'image_with_xmlID_0.xml'.  How to correct this?

Comment: I have corrected the code as there was some problems with filename and directory. Here are the updated lines:
os.rename(filename, os.path.join(_src,'ID_') + str(i)+_ext_jpg) os.rename(filename[:-4]+_ext_xml, os.path.join(_src,'ID_') + str(i)+_ext_xml)

Answer (score 0):

Using `glob`

**Ex:**

```
import os
import glob
_src = "path/to/directory"

for i,filename in enumerate(glob.glob("{}*.jpg".format(_src))):
    file = os.path.basename(filename)
    f, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
    os.rename(filename, os.path.join(_src, 'ID_' + str(i)+ext))   #Rename .jpg
    os.rename(os.path.join(_src, "{}.xml".format(f) , os.path.join(_src, 'ID_' + str(i)+".xml"))  #Rename .xml
```